# Searching for twitter users using javascript and axios

Tags: javascript, curl, twitter, get, axios

I am trying to connect to the twitter api in order to search for users using their username. I have read through the following documentation but am still unsure if im doing things correctly:

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/users/lookup/api-reference/get-users-by-username-username

Here is the code:

Axios instance:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({
    baseURL:"https://api.twitter.com/2/",
    header: {"Authorization": "Bearer $mybearertoken"}
});
```

Get request

```
export const searchForUser =(searchTerm)=> async (dispatch) => {

    const response = await twitter.get(`by/username/:${searchTerm}/TwitterDev?user.fields=profile_image_url,name`)

    dispatch({type:SEARCH_FOR_USER,payload:response.data})
};
```

I'm quite new to javascript, and using APIs so i have quite a few questions:

- The documentation uses curl requests. My understanding of curl requests is limited, so is it possible to perform the same action using nodejs and axios?
- Have I defined my axios instance correctly (e.g. defining the header)?
- If the answer is yes to the above, where am i going wrong?

I am also getting this error in my console "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.twitter.com/2/by/username/:j/TwitterDev?user.fields=profile_image_url,name' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

The HTTP error code is 400

Comment: CURL is one of the many ways to issue HTTP requests to Twitter API (and other internet hosts).

Comment: looks okay as long as you're importing that axios instance as `twitter` ?
How are you calling `searchForUser`? It will also return a Promise because of async. 
What response are you getting?

Comment: Are you actually setting your bearer token before calling that axios.create ?

Comment: I have copied it in after the $. I've also tried without the $ and neither work. I created the twitter developer account today but seeing as i was issued the token i imagine it should work right away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your server does not include the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in response to a preflight request (OPTIONS).

A CORS request will fail if Access-Control-Allow-Origin is missing. I suggest you use Node.js for API calls if you run into CORS error.

Here are some great articles that explain how CORS works:

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS